# Background Worker with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a webapp that's built on python/Flask and it has a corresponding background job that runs continuously, periodically polling for data for each registered user.

I would like this background job to start when the system starts and keep running til it shuts down. Instead of setting up /etc/rc.d scripts, I just had the flask app spawn a new process (using the multiprocessing  module) when the app starts up.

So with this setup, I only have to deploy the Flask app and that will get the background worker running as well.

What are the downsides of this? Is this a complete and utter hack that is fragile in some way or a nice way to set up a webapp with corresponding background task?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: 16K views, almost 5 years, 26 up-votes and just one answer. Python community, does everybody know, how to cook celery with flask in a right way? It would be nice to have a guide `How to use celery+flask for applications, larger that A+B`, because when you have 8-10 tasks and real non-trivial web-server code, covered with unit-tests, the existing flask-doc and celery-doc are lean and almost useless. Besides proposed `tasks.py` is probably a kludge in a real application, because in _real_ application it will be tightly coupled

Comment: @maxkoryukov It looks like your plea was answered. But it's still not easy!

Answer (score 11):

The downside of your approach is that there are many ways it could fail especially around stopping and restarting your flask application.

- You will have to deal with graceful shutdown to give your worker a chance to finish its current task.
- Sometime your worker won't stop on time and might linger while you start another one when you reboot your flask application.

Here are some approches I would suggest depending on your constraints:

#### script + crontab

You only have to write a script that does whatever task you want and `cron` will take care of running it for you every few minutes. *Advantages*: `cron` will run it for you periodically and will start when the system starts. *Disadvantages*: if the task takes too long, you might have multiple instances of your script running at the same time. You can find some solutions for this problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142002/generic-solution-to-prevent-a-long-cron-job-from-running-in-parallel).

#### supervisord

`supervisord` is a neat way to deal with different daemons. You can set it to run your app, your background script or [both](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#group-x-section-settings) and have them start with the server. Only downside is that you have to install `supervisord` and make sure its daemon is running when the server starts.

#### uwsgi

`uwsgi` is a very common way for deploying flask applications. It has few [features](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html) that might come in handy for managing background workers.

#### Celery

[Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/) is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well. I think this is the **best solution for scheduling background tasks** for a flask application or any other python based application. But using it comes with some extra bulk. You will be introducing at least the following processes:
- a broker (rabbitmq or redis)
- a worker
- a scheduler

You can also get `supervisord` to manage all of the processes above and get them to start when the server starts.

### Conclusion

In your quest of reducing the number of processes, I would highly suggest the `crontab` based solution as it can get you a long way. But please make sure your background script leaves an execution trace or logs of some sort.

Comment: On Windows: Celery sounded promising but relies on brokers which either rely Erlang or are not supported on Windows.  I think I'm leaning towards `crontab`, too! (Wait... does Windows have crontab? ... )