# Running a Flask server parallel to main app

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple game about hanoi towers that currently works in terminal. It allows the player to input his turn in terminal and outputs a visualization to terminal.

My task is to make a flask app that will open an html page where a JS script would poll the server for info about the game and double the visualization from terminal to the web page.

My problem is that both the game and flask have a main loop and if I run them sequently they won't work parallel.

So I need the game to run in terminal and the player to make turns in terminal, but I need the web server to get the game state and display it.

My question: what should I use for this? Threads of multiprocessing?

Say I have a flask view

```
from game import game

@app.route('/get_updates')
def get_updates():
   return flask.jsonify(game.instance().board)
```

How is it gonna work if flask and the game are running in separate threads? How can I get the game object from another thread?

Comment: You could start another thread and run Flask server in it, not that difficult.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384739/how-can-i-add-a-background-thread-to-flask

Comment: multi-threading is the simplest solution. You can share variables, objects between separate threads. You give the game object as parameter for the constructor of your flask thread

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May be its better to run your game in s different thread?

```
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template

class myGame(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.board = 1

    def run(self):
        pass


app = Flask(__name__)
game = myGame()

@app.route('/get_updates') 
def get_updates(): 
    return flask.jsonify(game.board)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game.start()
    app.run(port=81, host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start another thread and run Flask server in it.