# New Selenium webdriver for each session in a Flask app?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, session, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a webscraping Flask app that creates a new Webdriver instance for each user session, so that different users can scrape content from different pages. This would be simpler if the `driver.get()` and data collection happened in the same API call, but they can't due to the nature of the scraping I'll be doing. Here's what I have so far:

```python
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/get_site/<link>', methods=['GET'])
def get_site(link):
    session['driver'] = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    session['driver'].get(link)

    return 'link opened!'   # confirmation message

@app.route('/scrape_current_site', methods=['GET'])
def scrape_current_site():
    return session['driver'].title    # collecting arbitrary data from page

app.run()
```

This doesn't work, though:

`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encode'`

Conceptually a flask session *feels* like it's what I'm looking for (a new, unique object for each session), but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Store the browser instance in a global dictionary,
and use the session to store a user_id which is a key for you dict.

Also you should keep in mine if we initiate a browser for each user
we also should close it if user does not send any more request after a while.

I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22900255/7944100) to make a background timer program to clear non used browsers as well.

```
import atexit
import threading
import uuid
import time 

from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'any random string'

POOL_TIME = 5 #Seconds
MAX_OPEN_BROWSER_TIME = 60 #Seconds

#stores browser instance as value and user_id as key between requests
userBrowsers = {}
#user_id as key and unix time of last browser usage as value 
userLastuse = {}
dataLock = threading.Lock()
timerThread = threading.Thread()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def interrupt():
        global timerThread
        timerThread.cancel()

    def deleteUnusedBrowsers():
        global userBrowsers
        global timerThread

        with dataLock:
            for userId, lastuse in userLastuse.items():
                if time.time() - lastuse > MAX_OPEN_BROWSER_TIME:
                    del userBrowsers[userId]

        # runs this function after a delay
        timerThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, deleteUnusedBrowsers, ())
        timerThread.start()   

    def startTimer():
        global timerThread
        timerThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, deleteUnusedBrowsers, ())
        timerThread.start()

    startTimer()
    # When you kill Flask (SIGTERM), clear the trigger for the next thread
    atexit.register(interrupt)
    return app


app = create_app()


@app.route('/open_site/<url>', methods=['GET'])
def open_site(url):
    browser = get_browser()

    browser.get(url)
    return 'site opened!'


def get_browser():
    # check if user have an id in session or assign an id to user
    user_id = session.get("session-id")
    if user_id is None:
        user_id = uuid.uuid4()
        session["session-id"] = user_id

    # check if user have a browser instance or create one for user
    browser = userBrowsers.get(user_id)
    if browser is None:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        userBrowsers[user_id] = browser

    # updates last use time of browser
    userLastuse[user_id] = time.time()

    return browser
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the g module which persists over multiple requests from the same user

```
from flask import g
```

And attach the driver to g e.g.

```
g._driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
g._driver.get(link)
```