# Python Threading Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm creating a platform using flask+python where each loggedin user can add several social media accounts to be used for analysis. Each account added starts a new thread with the account name, which then is saved into a dic (key=account name and value=the thread). HOWEVER, when I do a hard refresh/reload on the homepage, the dic that references all the threads gets reset and returns None. I can make modifications, like get variable values from the threads or call the kill function to end the threads.I've been looking everywhere here on this site and I can't find the solution.

I've simplified my code:

```
class threads_manager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(threads_manager, self).__init__()

        self.cancelled = False
        self.accounts = {}

    def is_loggedin(self, username):
        if not self.accounts:
            return self.accounts[username].logged_in()

    def add_account(self, usname, uspass, PROXY):
        # AddAccount runs on a seperate thread that is managed by this thread
        acc = AddAccount(usname, uspass, '')
        acc.start()
        self.accounts.update({usname: acc})

    def kill_account(self, username):
        if self.accounts[username] != None:
            self.accounts[username].cancel()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def run(self):
         # make sure that the thread kill it self after 1 min as I cant
         #get access to it later                     
         while not self.cancelled:
             if self.timeout > 0:
                time.sleep(2)
                self.timeout -= 1
            else:
                self.cancelled = True

# create new instance as global variable
manager = threads_manager()

@app.route('/addAccounts/')
def addAccounts():
    global manager
    # for displaying the accounts that are already stored in the server
        #shows the names of the running threads (ajax call)
        if request.args.get('command') == 'GETACCOUNTS':
            tnames = []
            for t in threading.enumerate():
                tnames.append(t.name)
            # prints the names as a flash/toast
            return jsonify({'success' : tname})
        if request.args.get('command') == 'ADDACCOUNT':
            #ajax call
            manager.add_account('username', 'password', 'proxy')
        else:
            #when reloading the website
            return render_template('addAccounts.html')
```

Any help, ideas?

Comment: How about you use an actual database instead of an in-memory list/dict?

Comment: I could not edit so here's the 2 questions:
Q1: What am I doing wrong?

Q2: I'm running on the cheapest Ubuntu server from Digital-Ocean for 5$/month with 1 CPU. Is that good enough for this application or should I order a more expensive one with more CPU's?

Comment: Note: using the Flask-Admin plugin does most the account management for you

Comment: Q2: That is off topic for StackOverflow. Do a proper benchmark for your application and monitor the CPU usage before paying more than necessary

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm using MySQL as a database. Could you elaborate a bit more about how to use my database instead of an in-memory dic?
I'll look at Flask-Admin

Comment: While you're reading Flask-Admin, it gives you the option to use sqlalchemy library for your accounts http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding_a_new_model_backend/?highlight=sql

Comment: I've already looked, however. Does not solve my issue with not being able to access the threads I've started after the website has been reloaded

Comment: @cricket_007 I think you've misunderstood my issue. I don't need account management. I need a way to access running threads so I can control them

Comment: It's not clear why you think you need threads at all. The HTML is rendered in one thread. If you need content dynamically added after that, you need Javascript, not Python

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Threads is a must as I will be doing a bunch of calculations for each individual account added. It's about the backend and NOT frontend. Is it clear now @cricket_007 ?

Comment: I understood that part from the question. However, as you've observed, your dictionary isn't preserved between web requests. Hence, I suggest you use a database to store account information. You're welcome to use threads, but they should be separate processes from the web server. You can add background processes via Celery, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256002/background-worker-with-flask