# Checking if a flask server is busy or idle

Tags: python, flask

I want my flask server to do a certain task when its idle for some time lets say 5 mins, i.e after 5 mins it will do another job. For this i need something to check if a server is busy or idle. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background Worker with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256002/background-worker-with-flask)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current datetime in a variable everytime a request is made via the `@app.after_request` annotation.

Then you need a routine to periodically check if the time difference between now and the saved timestamp is greater than 5 miutes. If so then run your task.

For executing your check every 5 minutes you may need some kind of scheduler which will be started with your application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about the routine and scheduler. Thanks